# Find an abelian group $V$ and a field $F$ such that $(V,F)$ can define two distinct vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, examples-counterexamples

This is an exercise of *Advanced linear algebra* of Roman

> Find an abelian group $V$ and a field $F$ such that $(V,F)$ can define two distinct vector spaces.

That is: I must find two distinct definitions of scalar multiplication. What I did was choose $V:=(\Bbb R^2,+)$ as the abelian group, and $F:=\Bbb C$ as the field, and defined scalar multiplication by

1. $(a+bi)\cdot (x,y)=(ax-by,by+ax)$, this defines a vector space because its just the complexification of $\Bbb R$ as a vector space.
2. $(a+bi)\cdot (x,y)=(by+ax,ax-by)$ this is symmetric from the above definition.

But I dont found other example. Can someone show me a non so trivial example, or provide me a general rule to define such alternative scalar multiplications?

---

**UPDATE**: it seems that, from a known scalar multiplication defined by $d$, I can define an alternative scalar multiplication by $d\circ f$, where $f:V\to V$ is a group automorphism.

Comment: Are they meant to be distinct up to isomorphism or just distinct?

Comment: @Antonios-AlexandrosRobotis this is not stated in the exercise.